# Embedded pdf display affected by <!DOCTYPE html>?

Tags: html, pdf, doctype

I'm trying to embed a pdf into webpage and found a strange phenomenon. When I use this html:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38)">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" src="some.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</body>
</html>
```

Everything worked as expected. However, when I insert `<!DOCTYPE html>` into the first line, my browser only display part of the pdf.

[image]

Will anyone explain this strang behavior to me? It took me hours to figure out that it's the doctype line that's causing the problem so I'm really curious why.

Answer (score 0):

Doc types tell validators which version of HTML to use in checking the document's syntax. Here's a [list of DOCTYPES](http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html) that helps explain what each of them do.

You can probably also have the PDF file align & scale itself automatically by wrapping the embed tags with "p align" like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(38,38,38)">
<p align="center"><embed width="100%" height="100%" src="some.pdf" type="application/pdf"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know what DOCTYPE means.